# Handling Objects With Javascript Reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This is my object:

```
let data = [
        {acnumber: 1, acname: "Mr X", acterm: "shorterm", acbalance: 150},
        {acnumber: 2, acname: "Mr Y", acterm: "longterm", acbalance: 140},
        {acnumber: 3, acname: "Mr Z", acterm: "shorterm", acbalance: 155}
    ]
```

Because I need information about number of accounts and account balance for 'shortterm' loans only, I can filter this data this way:

```
let shortTerm = data.filter((item)=>{
        if (item.acterm === "shorterm") {
            return item;
        }
    })
```

Then I can find number of shortterm loan accounts using this:

```
let numberOfAccounts = shortTerm.length;
```

Also, I can find sum of account balance using this:

```
let accountBalance = shortTerm.reduce((acc, item)=>{
        return acc+item.acbalance;
    },0)
```

I was wondering if there is any better or more precise ways of getting the same result. I will highly appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

A single `.reduce` will work - add the property to the accumulator only if the object being iterated over is `shortterm`. Use concise return if you want.

```js
let data = [
        {acnumber: 1, acname: "Mr X", acterm: "shorterm", acbalance: 150},
        {acnumber: 2, acname: "Mr Y", acterm: "longterm", acbalance: 140},
        {acnumber: 3, acname: "Mr Z", acterm: "shorterm", acbalance: 155}
    ]
const balance = data.reduce(
  (a, obj) => a + (obj.acterm === 'shorterm' ? obj.acbalance : 0),
  0
);
console.log(balance);
```

Comment: This does show the account balance. How about the number of accounts? Is this possible to return both number of accounts and sum of account balance? Probably we can push these two results into an array [2, 305 ]. How can I achieve that?

Comment: If you need both, the clearest approach would be to do it in a separate operation. `const numAccounts = data.reduce((a, obj) => a + (obj.acterm === 'shortterm' ? 1 : 0), 0)`